# Laravel - Redirect authenticated users

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application I have a registration system that uses the default scaffolding created via `php artisan make:auth` to register new users, but after logging in I wanted to take the user to another page called `member-type` so that they can select what type of member they'd like to be.

I utilitized `protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)` which comes from `AuthenticatesUsers` to check that a user has successfully logged in, I then check whether a member type is set.

The method looks like this:

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    Log::info("{$user->log_reference} logged in to their account with IP: {$request->getClientIp()}");

    if(!$user->investor_type_selected){
        // dd('I NOT SELECTED');
        return redirect()->route('user.investor-type');
    } elseif(!$user->member_type_selected){
        dd('M NOT SELECTED');
        return redirect()->route('user.member-type');
    } else{
        dd('BOTH SELECTED');
        return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
    }
}
```

The methods `member_type_selected and`investor_type_selected`come from my`User` model and they look like this:

```
/**
 * Check whether this user has selected an investor type
 */
public function getInvestorTypeSelectedAttribute()
{
    return !empty($this->investor_type) ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Check whether this user has selected an investor type
 */
public function getMemberTypeSelectedAttribute()
{
    return !empty($this->member_type) ? true : false;
}
```

Pretty simple stuff.

The dump and die was there to test whether the statements were executing.

Anyway, the issue I have is with the Middleware `RedirectIfAuthenticated` which looks like this as I'm using a custom guard:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
            }
            break;
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Now, as soon as a user is authenticated this kicks in and bypasses my redirects with `authenticated`. I need this Middleware generally to make sure users get back to their dashboard, but is there a way to prevent this bypassing my redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to override `authenticated`  function , try this in your `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
               $user = Auth::guard($guard)->user();
                 if(!$user->investor_type_selected){
                  return redirect()->route('user.investor-type');
                } elseif(!$user->member_type_selected){
                  return redirect()->route('user.member-type');
                } else{
                  return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: in your LoginController , remove this  `$redirectTo` and try to check if it is working or not ?

Comment: Only issue then, is that it uses the default redirect path in RedirectsUsers

Comment: What you have done to solve redirect issue ? Is it working proper ?